# Fail to use quicklisp with clozure-cl

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf, clozure-cl

While using `SBCL` normally I want to try `CCL` for some testing and installed it via `homebrew` on my computer. That worked fine but I fail to use `quicklisp` with `CCL`. If I try to load quicklisp's `setup.lisp` I get the following error message:

```
➜  ~ ccl64
Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11.6  DarwinX8664

For more information about CCL, please see http://ccl.clozure.com.

CCL is free software.  It is distributed under the terms of the Apache
Licence, Version 2.0.
? (require 'asdf)
ASDF
("uiop" "UIOP" "asdf" "ASDF")
? (load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")                        
> Error: There is no package named "ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY" .
> While executing: CCL::%FASL-NVPACKAGE, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Retry finding package with name "ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY".
> Type :? for other options.
1 > :POP
```

I couldn't find a simple solution searching the web. `CCL` comes with `ASDF` as `(require 'ASDF)` is working. In quicklisp's documentation I couldn't find anything about extra efforts to use it with two lisp implementations in parallel.

If I check ASDF's version as suggested [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/How-do-I-detect-the-ASDF-version_003f.html) I get `"3.1.5"` as installed version, which should be quite recent.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it: I had some old data in my `~/.cache` directory from another attempt to install `ccl`. After deleting it, I can load quicklisp's `setup.lisp` without any error.

Please advice If I should delete my question or leave it here to prevent others from repeating my errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that various Lisps have some startup files. Some of them are by default:

- SBCL:  ~/.sbclrc
- CLISP: ~/.clisprc.lisp
- Clozure: ~/.ccl-init.lisp

From the [documentation](https://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#installing-and-running-clozure-cl) of CCL:

> By default, Clozure CL will look for a file named ccl-init.lisp in your home directory, and load it upon startup. On Unix systems, it will also look for .ccl-init.lisp.

CCL uses an ordinary lisp file called ccl-init.lisp which on unix systems is usually put on your home path. So you can add the following lines in that file (on my Ubuntu machine it's path is /home/me/.ccl-init.lisp) which instructs CCL to load quicklisp upon startup:

```
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

This is enough for enabling your CCL to communicate with quicklisp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I wrote in my answer the problem was not loading quicklisp itself but the process of loading ASDF afterwards.